# How to save custom ListView entries?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have two `EditText` and a `ListView` inside a `FragmentStatePager`. Everything works but the entries that I make with the `EditText` fields into the `ListView` will be added but when I click back they will not be saved. How is it possible to save them ?

*onCreateView*

```
final CustomListViewAdapter2 adapter2 = new CustomListViewAdapter2(getActivity(),
                R.layout.swipeviewrowitem, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter2);




        btnswipeview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View View) {

                if(wdhedittext.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Bitte Wiederholungszahl angeben",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
                    else if (kgedittext.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                        rowitem2 item = new rowitem2(wdhedittext.getText().toString() + "wdh", kgedittext.getText().toString());
                        adapter2.add(item);
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else{
                        rowitem2 item = new rowitem2(wdhedittext.getText().toString() + "wdh", kgedittext.getText().toString() + "kg");
                        adapter2.add(item);
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }




            }
        });
```

*CustomListViewAdapter* and *rowitem2*

```
class CustomListViewAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<rowitem2> {


        Context context;

        public CustomListViewAdapter2(Context context, int resourceId,
                                     List<rowitem2> items) {
            super(context, resourceId, items);
            this.context = context;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtTitle;
            TextView txtDesc;
        }



        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            rowitem2 rowItem = getItem(position);

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipeviewrowitem, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainText);
                holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
            holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
class rowitem2{

            private String edittexttitle;
            private String edittexttitle2;

            public rowitem2( String title, String desc) {
                this.edittexttitle = title;
                this.edittexttitle2 = desc;
            }

            public String getTitle() {
                return edittexttitle;
            }

            public String getDesc() {
            return edittexttitle2;
        }

            public void setTitle(String title) {
                this.edittexttitle = title;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return edittexttitle + "\n" + edittexttitle2;
            }


        }
```

Comment: did you get the answer you are looking for?

Comment: no unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know, what you mean by clicking back. But you create your adapter with the argument `rowItems`. You can add your items there and access them. This is the list you would want to save and when you are creating your ListView again, you need to pass this persistent list.

The method you are using to save your data, depends on the lifecycle. If it should be still there, when you start the app next time. you can use sqlite to save your rowitems and when you start your app, you create your list from that database.
If you just want to go back within your FragmentActivity you can just keep a reference to that list and pass it to your adapter, whenever it gets created again.

Comment: And how can I do it ?

Comment: What? Save your data with sqlite?

Comment: No to keep a reference to the list and pass it to my adapter.

Comment: You will have something like ´ArrayList<rowitem2> rowItems = new ArrayList<rowitem2>()´. You need to add this list to your main activity class. And create it for example in your onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save your EditText changes you will need to use some kind of saving on the return phase.

You can save the data in 3 Ways: SQL-Lite, write Data into File and my favorite save data on SharedPreferences.

all you need to do is create a list of Strings that will take all your EditText and saved it into SharedPreferences.

please read more about [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

Your activity has a life [Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)   so when you exit the activity all the data will be deleted.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The basic solution for your question is SQLite. Implement Sqlite in your project and you can fetch/retrieve your data to/from listview.